# MSK Connector w/ SMT

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I want to create an MSK Connector and want to add a temporary filter on the messages based on some values in the Kafka message. Is there any way to do this with an MSK Connector using SMT?

I don't see any documentation on it anywhere so I wanted to see if anyone was able to do it.